# Reject an email addressed to too many recipients in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Is there anyway to reject an email that is addressed to more than 5 recipients and have it bounce back to the sender with gmail? This is a long shot. Essentially I just don’t like receiving these “hey everybody! look at this” type of emails and I want people to know I don’t read them or even want them to come to my inbox without having to actually get all shirty about it.

Having looked at the [advanced search options](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7190), as far as I can tell, there isn’t even a way to filter by the number of recipients and even if there was the only thing you can do is to delete or archive the message, you can’t make it bounce.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no. With filters you can choose to:

- Skip the Inbox (Archive it)
- Mark as read
- Star it
- Apply the label:
- Forward it
- Delete it
- Never send it to Spam
- Always mark it as important
- Never mark it as important

There is no option to bounce. Bounce is done by the e-mail server when either an inbox is full or does not exist.